# How to configure AWS toolkit for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017

I have a visual studio project on vs2017 and I want to publish it on amazon.
I downloaded the toolkit from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/).
The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/getting-set-up.html) of aws tells me:

> To add a profile to the SDK Store
>
> Open AWS Explorer. In Visual Studio, choose the View menu, and then choose AWS Explorer or press Ctrl+K, and then press the A key.

But the problem is that I don't see anything about aws explorer in "view"? I downloaded + installed the toolkit but I can't find anything of it inside my visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

ATM there is only a [preview](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/preview-of-the-aws-toolkit-for-visual-studio-2017/) for the aws toolkit for visual studio 2017